# Get value of Capacitor of capacitive touch in the form of farads in Android and IPhone (kernel level )

Tags: android, ios, web, kernel

i want to access the value of capacitors of capacitive touch in android and iphone using background process application and than need to pass them to server is that possible

Answer (score 1):

The hardware for iOs devices is only exposed through the manufacturer-provided frameworks.

iOS does not give 3rd party developer kernel level access at all, so the answer for iOS is no.